# DataTemplate as resource with customizable bindings

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a `DataTemplate` that I use to present a value with symbol that looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:G} {1}">
                <Binding Path="DisplayValue" />
                <Binding Path="UnitSymbol" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

This template is repeated frequently in my XAML with different bindings (i.e. `DisplayValue` and `UnitSymbol` differs). I would like to create a `DataTemplate` as a resource and change the binding, e.g. something like `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyUnitTemplate, ValuePath=DisplayValue, UnitPath=UnitSymbol}"`. How can I achieve this?

Note! I realize I could create a custom data type that holds a value with unit and create a template for this type, but I'm curious to if it is possible to use resources as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you are looking for, and fairly easily. First, put your DataTemplate in a resources dictionary somewhere (or you can put it in the Windows or UserControl Resources section).

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<DataTemplate x:Name="TextBoxStyle">
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:G} {1}">
            <Binding Path="DisplayValue" />
            <Binding Path="UnitSymbol" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Then, in your usercontrol, reference the resource library.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SialTPChat.UI.Design;component/Styles/ResourceDic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Now you can use it anywhere in this usercontrol, and you can set the ItemsSource of the textbox to anything you want. IE,

```
   <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" /> //Set the ItemsSource to anything
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I also want to change the `Binding`s when I bind to the `DataTemplate` - `DisplaySymbol` and `UnitSymbol` will vary between each usage.

Comment: Ahh I understand. The best practice would be to create multiple datatemplates then, or create a model that is generic so that you do not need to change the bindings.